# Change single chord color in chord diagram using D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, chord-diagram

D3 and Javascript newbie here. I'd like to change the color of a single chord in a chord diagram that is rendered with D3. Ideally, this color can be arbitrary, with no relationship to the source/destination entities of the chord.

How do I identify a single chord so I can later access it to fill it?

[Here's an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4tiA.jpg) (poorly edited with an image editor) with the desired effect (green chord).

Answer (score 0):

```js
var matrix = [
  [11975,  5871, 8916, 2868],
  [ 1951, 10048, 2060, 6171],
  [ 8010, 16145, 8090, 8045],
  [ 1013,   990,  940, 6907]
];

var chord = d3.layout.chord()
    .padding(.05)
    .sortSubgroups(d3.descending)
    .matrix(matrix);

var width = 960,
    height = 500,
    innerRadius = Math.min(width, height) * .41,
    outerRadius = innerRadius * 1.1;

var fill = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(d3.range(4))
    .range(["#000000", "#FFDD89", "#957244", "#F26223"]);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

svg.append("g").selectAll("path")
    .data(chord.groups)
  .enter().append("path")
    .style("fill", function(d) { return fill(d.index); })
    .style("stroke", function(d) { return fill(d.index); })
    .attr("d", d3.svg.arc().innerRadius(innerRadius).outerRadius(outerRadius))
    .on("mouseover", fade(.1))
    .on("mouseout", fade(1));

var ticks = svg.append("g").selectAll("g")
    .data(chord.groups)
  .enter().append("g").selectAll("g")
    .data(groupTicks)
  .enter().append("g")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "rotate(" + (d.angle * 180 / Math.PI - 90) + ")"
          + "translate(" + outerRadius + ",0)";
    });

ticks.append("line")
    .attr("x1", 1)
    .attr("y1", 0)
    .attr("x2", 5)
    .attr("y2", 0)
    .style("stroke", "#000");

ticks.append("text")
    .attr("x", 8)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return d.angle > Math.PI ? "rotate(180)translate(-16)" : null; })
    .style("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.angle > Math.PI ? "end" : null; })
    .text(function(d) { return d.label; });

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "chord")
  .selectAll("path")
    .data(chord.chords)
  .enter().append("path")
    .attr("d", d3.svg.chord().radius(innerRadius))
    .style("fill", function(d) { return fill(d.target.index); })
    .style("opacity", 1)
.on("mouseover", function(){
    d3.select(this).style("opacity", 0.3); 
})
.on("mouseout", function(){
    d3.select(this).style("opacity", 1); 
});

// Returns an array of tick angles and labels, given a group.
function groupTicks(d) {
  var k = (d.endAngle - d.startAngle) / d.value;
  return d3.range(0, d.value, 1000).map(function(v, i) {
    return {
      angle: v * k + d.startAngle,
      label: i % 5 ? null : v / 1000 + "k"
    };
  });
}

// Returns an event handler for fading a given chord group.
function fade(opacity) {
  return function(g, i) {
    svg.selectAll(".chord path")
        .filter(function(d) { return d.source.index != i && d.target.index != i; })
      .transition()
        .style("opacity", opacity);
  };
}
```

```css
body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.chord path {
  fill-opacity: .67;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: .5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

I've just added functionality for mouse over and mouse out,

```
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "chord")
  .selectAll("path")
    .data(chord.chords)
  .enter().append("path")
    .attr("d", d3.svg.chord().radius(innerRadius))
    .style("fill", function(d) { return fill(d.target.index); })
    .style("opacity", 1)
.on("mouseover", function(){
    d3.select(this).style("opacity", 0.3); 
})
.on("mouseout", function(){
    d3.select(this).style("opacity", 1); 
});
```

In the above code see the mouseover and mouseout callbacks, 
Here I'm just changing the opacity, if you want to change the color, use fill attribute to fill the color.

Hope you are looking for this.
If not ask me for more.
:D

Comment: Thanks for answering. However, in your solution, the opacity changes when you hover the mouse over a chord. My question was intended to change the color of the chord without needing any interaction from the user. That is, to set the color of an individual chord, manually, without the need of hovering the mouse over it. I was thinking about using selectAll() to pick one, but I don't know how to reference a unique chord.